discrete random variable probability question
I have homework in probability and hope it's not against the rules to post them here, I read them and didn't find anything about HW questions so sorry if it is.
I'll describe the question first and then what I tried, I don't seem to understand why my answer is incorrect (I don't know the answer but it is an american style question and my answer is not there).
Question:
A seller sells 3 types of bottles and has in total 25 of them: 10 juice bottles, 7 cola bottles and 8 water bottles.
15 people bought a bottle at random from the given stock each bought exactly 1 bottle.
let X be the amount of water bottles left in the sellers stock after the purchases.
what is the value of P{X = 3}.
What I tried: I know that for X = 3 he have to sell 5 bottles of water so we are left with needing to sell 10 bottles from the cola and/or juice and that is 8 pairs of different combinations (cola=0, juice=10), (cola=1, juice=9) and so on or in other words 0 <= cola <= 7 and we have enough juice bottles to complete the 10.
the total amount of combinations I calculated and summed 9 cases of 0 <= water <= 8 so when water = 0 then cola + juice = 14 so cola have to be at least 5 because we only have 10 juice bottles and at max 7 because that's the max amount of cola bottles and so for water = 0 I have 3 cases.
here are all the cases I calculated (goes from left to right starts with water=0 and ends at water=8): 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8.
summing this up I get 57 so now I divide the the cases with X = 3 by X != 3 which is 8/57 and this is the answer I get but it's wrong so I'd like an explenation on why that is wrong and what is the correct way.

The problem is that the different combinations you look at are not equally probable.   As a hint for the problem:  just think of it as $17$ non-water bottles, and $8$ waters.  How many selections take exactly $5$  waters?

@lulu maybe $\frac{\binom{8}{5} \binom{17}{10}}{\binom{25}{15}}$ ? which is equal to 0.3332

There you go!   If you like, you can post your own solution below.  That way people here can check your work and the site can close the question.

Big thanks for @lulu for the help! the answer to this question is $\frac{\binom{8}{5} \binom{17}{10}}{\binom{25}{15}} = 0.3332$ in my understanding we choose 5 water bottles from the group of 8 using binom, multiply by choosing the 10 remaining bottles to sell from the 17 total remaining bottles (we don't count the remaining 3 water bottles because we don't want to sell them in this scenario and divide by the total amount of sales which is choose 15 from 25.
